# How do I upgrade the clang on my Mac running OS/X El Capitan to LLVM 3.8?

Tags: c++, macos, llvm, openmp, llvm-clang

I downloaded the Mac binary version of llvm-3.8 from llvm.org but am uncertain how to install it to replace the existing version of clang that shipped with the machine.  I want to upgrade because I need support for the OpenMP library which is included in the latest version.

Comment: I would recommend using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). You can simply run `brew install clang`. Is the version included with the latest Xcode not sufficient?

Comment: Yes, I need a compiler that supports the -fopenmp flag which the installed version doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/YourdesiredXcode.app

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you don't **replace** any Apple-provided version of Clang, you configure your shell to find your preferred third-party Clang instead. For example, you put a line like `export PATH="/path/to/custom/clang/bin:$PATH"` in your .bashrc file.

Beyond that, there is no Clang "shipped with the machine". There's an executable at `/usr/bin/clang`, but that's not really Clang. It's a trampoline that runs something else. If neither Xcode nor the Command Line Tools are installed, it will prompt you to install one of those. If one of those has been installed, it will run the Clang that comes with it.

Comment: I know that xcode wraps other compilers.  Is there a way to let xcode know it should use the new version?  That may have been a more precise statement.  I am concerned not only about being able to use it but eventually making sure it plays nice with code signing.